# Talking about a specific place to people who doesn't know this place

Tags: word-in-context

Let’s say I want to describe something that occurred at a specific place (althought the place where it occurred isn’t important at all - I’m just mentioning it) but the people I’m talking to doesn’t know anything about this place. So if I say something like…

> I was spending some time at the bar last night when an idea popped
>   into my head.

Does this phrase make any sense? Would people ask themselves "what bar is this guy talking about?" Should I be more specific and say something like:

> I was spending some time at a bar near my house last night when an
>   idea popped into my head.

or

> I was spending some time at the new bar around the corner last night
>   when an idea popped into my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example phrase does make sense, and wouldn't necessarily make me think "what bar is this guy talking about?" - in colloqial British English at least, it is very common to say "I was down the pub the other week" and for it to be understood "the" pub is probably the speaker's local/habitual pub, and/or whatever pub they happened to be in, it doesn't matter.

In a strictly grammatical sense, however, it does imply a specific bar, and in different contexts with different speakers it is possible a listener may find themselves which place you mean.  To make it more clear the particular bar/place does not matter, you could simply say "I was spending some time at a bar last night..."  Using the indefinite article with no qualification ("around the corner") is an implicit  statement that the specific X is irrelevant.

Adding further description / qualification of the particular bar could add useful context or simply colour to the anecdote, or it could be seen as extraneous information, distracting from the point.  It's up to you, no right or wrong.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for all the explanation, it really helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Is the person you are talking to likely to ask 'Which bar?'. Generally, we tell people as much as they need to know to understand what we are saying. If your idea could have popped into your head at any bar, then it is not important to say exactly which bar you were at (but you *can*). If your idea is somehow related to exactly which bar you are in, then it's more important to say so: I was spending some time at a bar near my house last night when an idea popped into my head. *I could dig a tunnel from here to my house.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer and tips, that's awesome.